# How to remove content inside double parenthesis in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, wikipedia-api

I am fetching some data from wikipedia and it has some contents inside parenthesis, I want to remove all the contents inside the parenthesis. I am able to remove the data when the parenthesis is single using `content.replace(/\s*\(.*?\)\s*/g, '')` but for some data parenthesis is double and triple. Please help me to get the expected output.

**Input**

> Russia ( ( listen); Russian: Росси́я, tr. Rossíya, IPA: [rɐˈsʲijə])
>   officially the Russian Federation

**Expected Output**

> Russia officially the Russian Federation

**Output which I am getting now**

> Russia; Russian: Росси́я, tr. Rossíya, IPA: [rɐˈsʲijə]) officially the
>   Russian Federation

Comment: What if input is `Russia ( ( listen); Russian: Росси́я, tr. Rossíya, IPA: [rɐˈsʲijə]) officially the (soviet) Russian Federation` ?

Comment: Output should be **Russia officially the Russian Federation** but mostly strings sounds better If we remove parenthesis from the wikipedia text.

Comment: You cannot match nested brackets using JS regex. Write a parser instead.

Comment: How to write a parser to do this? I am new to parser, can you please share some links to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot match nested brackets using JS regex. Hare is a basic parser code to do the job:

```js
var str = 'Russia ( ( listen); Russian: Росси́я, tr. Rossíya, IPA: [rɐˈsʲijə]) officially the Russian Federation (Russian: Российская Федерация, tr. Rossiyskaya Federatsiya, IPA: [rɐˈsʲijskəjə fʲɪdʲɪˈratsɨjə]), is a sovereign country in Eurasia. At 17,125,200 square kilometres (6,612,100 sq mi)';

var result = '';
var lvl = 0;
for (var i = 0, len = str.length; i < len; i++) {
  var ch = str.charAt(i);
  if (ch == '(')
    lvl++;

  if (lvl == 0)  
    result += ch;

  if (ch == ')')
    lvl--;
}

console.log(result.replace(/\s{2,}/g, ' '));
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```js
var text = "Russia ( ( listen); Russian: Росси́я, tr. Rossíya, IPA: [rɐˈsʲijə]) officially the Russian Federation"

console.log(text.replace(/\s*\(.*\)/,''));
```

Comment: Thanks but it fails If I have another parenthesis set in the same string. example: Russia ( ( listen); Russian: Росси́я, tr. Rossíya, IPA: [rɐˈsʲijə]) officially the (soviet) Russian Federation.

Comment: will the `]` be there always before `)`

Comment: Original string which I need to convert is **Russia ( ( listen); Russian: Росси́я, tr. Rossíya, IPA: [rɐˈsʲijə]) officially the Russian Federation (Russian: Российская Федерация, tr. Rossiyskaya Federatsiya, IPA: [rɐˈsʲijskəjə fʲɪdʲɪˈratsɨjə]), is a sovereign country in Eurasia. At 17,125,200 square kilometres (6,612,100 sq mi)**

Comment: I am directly getting the content from wikipedia. Anything inside () should not come in output.

Answer (score 1):

This might be a long answer. But the logic works for any case.

```js
var text = "Russia ( ( listen); Russian: Росси́я, tr. Rossíya, IPA: [rɐˈsʲijə]) officially the (soviet) Russian Federation"

function replaceParenthesis(text) {

  var counter = 0,
    startIndex = 0,
    endIndex = 0,
    parts = [],
    output = text;

  for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
    if (text[i] === "(") {
      if (counter == 0) {
        startIndex = i;
      }
      counter++;
    } else if (text[i] === ")") {
      counter--;
      if (counter == 0) {
        endIndex = i + 1;
        parts.push(text.substring(startIndex, endIndex));
      }
    }
  }

  parts.forEach(function(part) {
    output = output.replace(part, '');
  });

  return output;

}

console.log(replaceParenthesis(text));
```

Comment: Thanks. I will check this solution too. :)

Answer (score 0):

Another naive method (Here I'm only removing the parenthesis, not removing spaces).

```js
var str = "Russia ( ( listen); Russian: Росси́я, tr. Rossíya, IPA: [rɐˈsʲijə]) officially the Russian Federation";
    var output = str.substring(0,str.indexOf("(")) + str.substring(str.lastIndexOf(")")+1,str.length);
    console.log(output);
```

Comment: It works but it's failing when I have more than one parenthesis set in the same string. **Russia ( ( listen); Russian: Росси́я, tr. Rossíya, IPA: [rɐˈsʲijə]) officially the Russian Federation (Russian: Российская Федерация, tr. Rossiyskaya Federatsiya, IPA: [rɐˈsʲijskəjə fʲɪdʲɪˈratsɨjə]), is a sovereign country in Eurasia. At 17,125,200 square kilometres (6,612,100 sq mi)**

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be to use the `extract` or `extract_html` fields of the summary REST endpoint for this: https://en.wikipedia.org/api/rest_v1/page/summary/Russia.

Note: While it aims to remove most of the pronunciations, this does not blindly remove all parentheses. E.g. you don't want to remove all parentheses, esp. when it comes to complex chemical formulas. Also, single words inside parentheses are kept.